# Magento 2 add blank column to custom admin grid

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

Is it possible to add blank column into a custom admin grid module? this is the code of my ui_component

```
<columns name="spinner_columns">
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
    <column name="increment_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="company">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">company</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">15</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>                    
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="updated_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Modified</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

Comment: no offense, but why would you want that?

Comment: @PhilippSander easily for copy&paste for other usage

Comment: copy&paste? a blank column?

Comment: yes, if no blank column, user have to insert column using excel

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add blank column in admin grid.

Just add below code in your ui-component xml file.

```
<columns name="spinner_columns">
    <column name="id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

This code will add blank column in your admin grid.

Comment: Just tried, "Something went wrong" modal was shown

Comment: name="id" =>  name="" seems work

Comment: You must have to give name for column. You can not pass blank value for name attribute.

Comment: If you don't want to add data in column then pass any dummy name. And if you want data in column then you have to pass **database table field name** as name attribute value like **name="<table_fieldName>"**